# Unable to send DateTime property as expected to WebAPI

Tags: html, datetime, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

Hi I trying to send the data from my Helper

```
var request = new RestRequest("Controller/ActionName", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddBody(Model);
var response = _client.Execute(request);
```

the following are the properties that are in my Model

```
public DateTime FromDate{get; set;}
public DateTime ToDate{get; set;}
```

When I am sending the FromDate/ToDate from the controller, a Day in the FromDate  and ToDate is getting reduced.
For example, If I send the DateTime as "29-03-2015" the value I am getting in the API is "28-03-2015".
The DTO in the API is

```
public DateTime FromDate{get;set}
public DateTime ToDate{get;set;}
```

Can some one please help me out

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the proper date? Are you checking both client side and server side debuggers to ensure the proper values are being sent and mapped to the appropriate variables?

Comment: Hi, Except the DateTime variables, remaining all the variables are mapped appropriately as expected.

Comment: Ok, can you show where the date times are being initialized and set in the helper

Comment: I am initialising the DateTime variables in this way, 

`<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" name="FromDate"/>` in view. I am using Boostrap datepicker to get the  FromDate and ToDate

Now, in the Website Controller,
`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertData(DataModel model)
{
//code here
}`
am able to get all the variables into the model as expected in the website including the DateTime variables.
As soon as I debug the line `var response = _client.Execute(request);` as mention above, It goes to the service carrying all the variables including DateTime by decreasing a day.

Comment: The Date format of  Date picker is different to that of my PC's Date format. 
Is this may be because of different Date formats?

Comment: Could be, have you checked the time zone element of the date time objects? It could be there is a time zone difference you're not accounting for

Comment: There is a difference of 12hours 30 mins in my local to the server. 
This is how I have done to solve the issue,
`DateTime fromDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(Dto.FromDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);`// here I jus got the same one day delayed date.
`TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC+12");
Dto.FromDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(fromDate, timeZone);` //Now here I got the expected date.
Hmm..May be this will help me temporarily.